# MySQL/PHP data sort order

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need data to be sorted in a particular order when output from a MySQL database into PHP. Would it be better to reindex the table? (I hesitate to do this since there are foreign constraints.) Or, would it be better create a new `sort_order` column in the table? How would I <s>manually</s> update this `sort_order` column? I have tested this in MySQL Workbench and found it to be a giant PITA.

The index column and `sort_order` column would both contain unique integers. The actual order I want the records to be in when outputted is more or less arbitrary.

Here is some sample data:

```
ID      DATA
1       Yellow
2       Red
3       Cyan
4       Green
```

Here is my desired order:

```
ID      DATA
2       Red
1       Yellow
4       Green
3       Cyan
```

Comment: Without data and what or how you want it sorted, it is hard to find a solution.

Comment: The index column and sort_order column would both contain integers. The actual order I want the records to be in when outputted is more or less arbitrary.

Comment: Uh, this is confusing. First you say you want the data sorted, then you say the actual order you want is "more or less arbitrary." I think you should show an example of the data and show what is the order you want it sorted.

Comment: By the way, tables do not have a sort order. Query results have a sort order, and you achieve this by using an `ORDER BY` clause in the proper position in your SELECT query.

Comment: I updated with some sample data.

Comment: I want to know how I can modify my table so that I can then use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: You can use ORDER BY on any column. No changes required. Of course some are more suited than others

Comment: Unfortunately the order you want does not conform to any kind of sort. So you may need to add a `order` column and place the correct number in there and then ORDER the resultset BY that new column

Comment: I know this. This is why I specifically mentioned it as a possible solution in my question.

Comment: With the other option being reindexing the table, which I am hesitant about doing.

Comment: See FIELD() in the manual

Comment: This would solve the ordering problem, but I would have to update the FIELD list every time I add or remove a record.

Comment: If the order of every row is important then yes, that's true ; in which case, a sort_order column is the way to go.

Comment: Would it be possible to write a script such that I can specify the `sort_order` number I want a new record to be at, and the rest of the records will adjust themselves up or down accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is to add a new integer column "order" at the end of your table and then do:

```
SELECT FROM table ORDER BY order
```

I would recommend using order values in multiples of 10s...

10, 20, 30, etc.   Just in case you need to add values between them, it is easier to add them instead of moving all the ordered values.

For the frontend part, you may use something like the following:

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable

(Check jQueryUI draggable + sortable)

and submit your form and update the "order" column accordingly.

Comment: Your suggestion would be easier to perform manually. But I still could run out of integers between 10 and 20 for instance. Is there a method that could also be automated?

Comment: How would you _not_ do it manually if the order does not follow any recognisable pattern? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm not convinced someone would need to go into Workbench and edit each and every record by hand. (Though if it were possible to insert a new record or change the order without a lot of effort in Workbench it would be a great bonus!) Could a script be created where someone just types in the position he or she wants a new record to be in, and adjust the other records automatically to accommodate the new record? And perform the opposite operation when a record is deleted?

Comment: You would need to do a frontend administration using drag and drop functionality and update your data accordingly.

Comment: I was hoping for a SQL query or stored procedure that I might use, but the "drag and drop" frontend answer will have to suffice.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case of colours, you could of course store their wavelengths...

```
CREATE TABLE spectrum
(colour VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,wavelength_range_start_nm INT NOT NULL
,wavelength_range_end_nm INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO spectrum VALUES
('Violet',380,450),
('Blue',450,485),
('Cyan',485,500),
('Green',500,565),
('Yellow',565,590),
('Orange',590,625),
('Red',625,740);

SELECT colour FROM spectrum ORDER BY wavelength_range_start_nm DESC;
+--------+
| colour |
+--------+
| Red    |
| Orange |
| Yellow |
| Green  |
| Cyan   | -- Wikipedia lists cyan; it was always ROYGBIV when I was at school!
| Blue   |
| Violet |
+--------+
```

More generally, where a custom order is required, use FIELD().

Comment: My color table has non-spectral hues as well. Plus I have other tables with genres of fiction in them. Your suggestion won't work with those.